# linux discord.js Commands are not getting set with fs discord.js

Tags: javascript, linux, terminal, discord, discord.js

I am getting nothing when I do .sping and it is really confusing me when I do .sping in discord I get my stuff in my terminal but Running Command and Command Run and when I set my commands in the ready part it says ready before any of the logs are put in the terminal. It is annoying as I am separating my commands into files and I can't get any of them to work as my bot is for my discord server as I want to replace one of my old bots that run discord 11 and I don't want that bot anymore so I was making a new discord js bot and I am unable to get this to work can you guys help me correct my code as this will be bad for my server.

My index.js code

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const Bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

Bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

var prefix = ".s";

console.log("Sentry's Token Is " + config.token);

Bot.login(config.token);

Bot.on("ready", () => {
  fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    var jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
    if (jsfiles.length <= 0) {
      return console.log("No commands found..");
    } else {
      console.log(jsfiles.length + " commands found.");
    }

    jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
      var cmds = require(`./commands/${f}`);
      console.log(`Command ${f} loading..`);
      Bot.commands.set(cmds.config.command, cmds);
    });
  });

  console.log("Ready!");
});

Bot.on("message", message => {
  var msgl = message.content.toLowerCase();
  var msg = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
  var args = msg.slice(1);

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
    console.log("Prefix");
    var cmd = Bot.commands.get();
    console.log("Cmd");
    if (cmd) {
      console.log("Running command");
      cmd.run(Bot, msg, args);
      console.log("Command was ran");
    }
  }
});
```

My ping.js Code

```js
module.exports.run = async (Bot, message, args) => {
  console.log("Ping! Pong!");
  message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      title: "Ping!",
      description: "Pong!",
      color: 0x17a589
    }
  });
  console.log("Ping! Pong!");
};

module.exports.config = {
  command: "ping"
};
```

My outcome

> Sentry's Token Is XXXXX
> Ready!
> 1 commands found.
> Command ping.js loading..
> Prefix
> Cmd

Locations:

```
Server:
  index.js,
  commands:
    ping.js
```